# function equation $f(x)+f(y)=f(\frac {x+y} {1+xy})$

Tags: functional-equations

Is there exist $f:(-1,1)\to R$ such that $f(x)+f(y)=f(\frac {x+y} {1+xy})$?
how to find $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume $f'(0)$ exist.

for $|x|<1$, we can find relatively small $H$ such that $|h|<H\,$ implies $1 - x^2 - xh\neq0$ .

I will define y = $\frac{h}{1-x^2 - xh}$.

Then
$$
y - x^2 y = h + xyh = h(1+xy)\\ \Rightarrow \frac{y - x^2 y}{1+xy} = \boldsymbol{\frac{x+y}{1+xy} - x = h.}
$$

Now, $f(x+h) - f(x) = f(y) = f(\frac{h}{1-x^2 - xh})$.

Moreover, $f(0) = 0$ is easily checked. ($x=y=0$ on original equation)

Thus
$$
f'(x) =\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}  = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(\frac{h}{1-x^2 - xh}) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(\frac{h}{1-x^2 - xh}) - f(0)}{\frac{h}{1-x^2 - xh}} \frac{1}{1-x^2 - xh}\\=\frac{f'(0)}{1-x^2}
$$

Of course, $h$ varies in the range $|h|<H\,$.

now, for $|x|<1$ , $$f(x) = f(x)-f(0) = \int_{0}^{x} f'(t) dt = f'(0) \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-t^2} 
 dt  = \frac{C}{2} (\, \ln|1+x| - \,\ln|1-x|),$$

Where $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

The functional equation for hyperbolic tangent is
$$ g(x):=\tanh(x),\quad g(x+y) = \frac{g(x)+g(y)}{1+g(x)g(y)}. $$ The Wikipedia article
[Hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions) is one source for this.

The functional equation for its inverse function is
$$ f(x):=\tanh^{-1}(x),\quad f(x)+f(y) = f\Big(\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\Big). $$

Note that, just like with [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), without any
other assumptions such as continuity, and so on, there
could be many strange solutions. Consult the Wikipedia
article for details.