# Determine all the continuous functions $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x,y \in (-1,1)$, $f(x)+f(y)=f(\frac{x+y}{1+xy})$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Determine all the continuous functions $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x,y \in (-1,1)$, $f(x)+f(y)=f(\frac{x+y}{1+xy})$.

My attempt: For $x=y=0$, $2f(0)=f(0) \iff f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$. However, $f(0)=1 \Rightarrow f(x)=f(\frac{x+0}{1+x\cdot0})=f(x)+f(0)=f(x)+1$, and this gives $0=1$, false.

So, $f(0)=0$. Also, for $y=-x$, $f(x)+f(-x)=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=-f(-x)$, so $f$ is an odd function.
Also I observed that $f(x)+f(-y)=f(x)-f(y)$, so $f(x)-f(y)=f(\frac{x-y}{1-xy})$.

I observe that there is a resemblance with the tangent of the sum: $\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}$, but that minus in $1-xy$ just does not fit with the plus in $1+xy$. So I think $\arctan$ is not a response.

Any help, please?

Comment: one solution is $$f(x) = \tanh^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\ln\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}.$$
You might be able to prove uniqueness by considering inverse of $f$, if you could show that inverse exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function equation $f(x)+f(y)=f(\frac {x+y} {1+xy})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538965/function-equation-fxfy-f-frac-xy-1xy). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%2Bf(y)%3Df(%5Cfrac%7Bx%2By%7D%7B1%2Bxy%7D)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, consider $g(x) = f(\tanh x):$
$$g(x) + g(y) = f\left(\dfrac{\tanh x + \tanh y}{1+\tanh x\tanh y}
\right) = f(\tanh(x+y)) = g(x+y),$$
so $g$ solves the Cauchy equation. It's well-known that when you add continuity requirement on Cauchy equation, the only solution is $g(x) = ax$, which have been solved thoroughly on this site. In fact, only the continuity at $x = 0$ would be enough.

Comment: you don't even need that comment now which I wrote before I had this realization. Now you have $f(\tanh x) = ax$ for some constant $a$ and this should imply $f(y) =a \tanh^{-1}y$ already. Just check that the domains check out.